# "Постричься" или "поДстричься"?

Tags: лексика

Как правильно?

Comment: Что «Как правильно»? Что знать-то хотите? Где ваша версия правильного?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотря, в каком значение употреблено слово.
Когда речь идет о стрижке, чаще всего употребляется слово "поДстригать", слово же "постричь" больше относится к понятию "пОстриг в монахи", то есть церковный обряд.
Впрочем, в русском языке имеют место оба слова.

Answer (score 5):

### Короткая версия:

Правильно - *"постричься"*, в общем случае. *"Подстричься"* можно
использовать для обозначения лёгкой стрижки для сохранения формы уже
имеющейся причёски.

### Длинная версия:

*"Стричь"* означает *"отрезать волосы"*.

Суффикс *"ся"* означает применение действия на себя. *"Стричься"* - *"отрезать себе волосы"*. Тот факт, что само действие часто производится третьим лицом (парикмахером) лингвистически не отражается (поэтому не следует придираться к тому, что когда ты "отрезаешь себе волосы", ты на самом деле часто делаешь это не сам).

Приставка *"по"* означает законченность действия. *"Стричься"* не говорит о том, была ли стрижка закончена. *"Постричься"* говорит о том, что стрижка была закончена (*"постригся"*) или будет закончена (*"пострижётся"*).

Приставка *"под"* имеет несколько значений, некоторые из которых могут быть неочевидны. Рекомендую проконсультироваться со словарём. Что касается *"подстричься"*, то здесь, как мне кажется, приставка *"под"* означает малый масштаб действия (и, я думаю, также включает в себя значение приставки *"по"*, означая законченность действия). *"Ровнять"* - *"делать ровным"* (тоже, кстати, относится к стрижке - *"подровнять виски"*). *"Подровнять"* - *"немного сделать ровным"* (подразумевается, что ровняемый объект уже почти ровный). Соответственно, *"подстричь"* - *"немного стричь то, что уже было стрижено"*, то есть поправить (подправить!) причёску. Это слово плохо подходит для ситуаций, когда форма и/или длина волос меняется радикальным образом (если, конечно, не имеет место быть сарказм).

У слова *"постричь"* есть и другое значение - *"принять постриг"*, но это относится к религии (не знаю, является ли изменение причёски частью пострига; мне кажется, что является).

Answer (score 4):

ПОДСТРИЧЬСЯ, -стригусь, -стрижёшься, -стригутся; подстригся, -лась, -лось; св.
Подстричь или давать подстричь себе волосы. < Подстригаться, -аюсь, -аешься; нсв.

ПОСТРИЧЬСЯ, -стригусь, -стрижёшься, -стригутся; постригся, -лась, -лось; св.
1.
Постричь себе волосы. П. в парикмахерской. Тебе пора п. П. под мальчика, под бокс
(сделать себе определённую причёску).
2. Церк.
Принять постриг, стать монахом. П. в монахи. < Постригаться, -аюсь, -аешься; нсв.

http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?bts=x&word=%CF%EE%2A%F1%F2%F0%E8%F7%FC%F1%FF

Comment: Копирование статьи с чужого сайта не является ответом. Пишите от себя и так, чтобы это людям могло пригодиться. Вы на вопрос не ответили.

Answer (score 2):

Подстричься - укоротить длину волос.
Постричься - сделать стрижку, имеющую какое-то название

Answer (score 1):

Вот аналогия напрашивается: постричься - поДстричься, помыться - поДмыться. Как говорится, почувствуйте разницу.